# Pass a string as a char pointer array using ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a `C` function of this signature:

`int fileopen(const char *fname, int flags)`

In Linux system, I want to pass the `fname` from Python using `ctypes` so I use `ctypes.c_char_p("file1.dat")` as the following:

```
import ctypes as ctypes

dll_name = "IO/pyaio.so"
dllabspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + os.path.sep + dll_name
pyaio = ctypes.CDLL(dllabspath)

fd_w = pyaio.fileopen(ctypes.c_char_p("file1.dat"), 1)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    fd_w = pyaio.fileopen(ctypes.c_char_p("file1.dat"), 1) # 0 read, 1 write
TypeError: bytes or integer address expected instead of str instance
```

I don't know another way to pass the string`"file1.dat"` than using `ctypes.c_char_p`. How to solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `"file1.dat"` to `b"file1.dat"` (which is the same you would get with `'file1.dat'.encode('ascii')`).

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much